# Objective-C class type mismatch after cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

After parsing the JSON response from a webservice using `NSJSONSerialization`, I use `+isKindOfClass:` to make sure the server returned the kind of data I expect. Using this method, I ran into some weird behaviour, which I'll illustrate using an example.

Consider the following objects:

```
// Definitions
NSDictionary *son = @{ @"firstname" : @"James", @"lastname" : @"Appleseed" };
NSDictionary *daughter = @{ @"firstname" : @"Susan", @"lastname" : @"Appleseed"};
NSArray *children = @[son, daughter];
NSDictionary *father = @{ @"firstname" : @"John", @"lastname" : @"Appleseed" };
NSDictionary *family = @{@"children" : children, @"father" : father};
NSDictionary *pedigree = @{@"family" : family };
```

Those objects represent deserialized JSON returned from a server. Now if I want to use the array of children to calculate how much children there are using NSArray's `-count`, I need to make sure the children object is an NSArray. If the children object for example happens to be a string, while the app expects an array, it'll crash because strings don't implement a `count` method. Consider the following code sequence which implements the described check:

```
// First test
id _family = [pedigree objectForKey:@"family"];
if ([_family isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSDictionary *_family = (NSDictionary *)_family;
    id _children = [_family objectForKey:@"children"];

    NSLog(@"Children: %@", _children);
    NSLog(@"Children classname: %@", NSStringFromClass(children.class));

    if ([_children isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Children is an NSArray");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Children is not an NSArray");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Family is not an NSDictionary");
}
```

After running this code, the console outputs the following:

```
Children: (null)
Children classname: __NSArrayI
Children is not an NSArray
```

The console output appears to be extremely remarkable and even contradictory. How could children *not* be an NSArray while its classname is __NSArrayI?

After a bit of debugging, I found that there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. remove this line `NSDictionary *_family = (NSDictionary *)_family;`
2. use a different name than `_family` for the casted variable

How could this behaviour be explained?

Comment: Generally you should not use variable names beginning with `_` for local variables.  The `_` prefix is reserved for the instance variables behind properties and for system names.  (As you can see from your problem, there are good reasons to observe this rule.)

Comment: I know, this was just for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
NSDictionary *_family = (NSDictionary *)_family;
```

you define a new variable `_family` in the current scope, which makes the outer variable `_family` invisible. Objective-C pointers are initialized to `nil` if you compile with ARC.

And the output is not contradictory, because you print

```
NSStringFromClass(children.class);
```

which is the class of `children` (without the underscore), which is an array. But `_children` (with underscore) is `nil` because `_family` is nil as explained above.

In fact you don't need a type cast if you expect a dictionary. You could just do

```
NSDictionary *_family = [pedigree objectForKey:@"family"];
if ([_family isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSArray *_children = [_family objectForKey:@"children"];

    if ([_children isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Children is an NSArray");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Children is not an NSArray");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Family is not an NSDictionary");
}
```

Comment: Dangit, the children.class was a stupid typo. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `children` contains an array, your variable `_children` is `nil`.

This explains the first `NSLog` that prints `(null)` (because you log `_children`, not `children`), but the second `NSLog` that prints `__NSArrayI` (because you print the class of the `children` object, not the class of the nil `_children` variable.

Your third `NSLog` says that it is not an array because you check for `[_children isKindOfClass:...]` and `_children` is `nil`, so `[nil isKindOfClass:...]` returns `NO`.

---

So to solve your problem, you have to figure out why your `_children` variable is `nil` (while your `children` variable isn't).

And this is obviously because you use a `_family` variable that shadows its parent. So the line `NSDictionary *_family = (NSDictionary *)_family;` obviously use the internal `_family` variable, and has the exact same behavior as if you wrote `NSDictionary *foo = (NSDictionary *)foo;`: as this `foo` is `nil`, casting it to whatever you want will still make it `nil`.

Use a different name for your internal `_family` variable to avoid the second `_family` variable shadows the outer `_family` variable, and your problem will go away. Or better, remove this line completely, as there is no problem calling a method on `id` without casting (that's what `id` is for, actually)